# Facebook SDK 2.8 doesnot give email address

Tags: facebook, sdk

I am trying to implement FacbookSDK 2.8 for my website and below is the simplified version of the code.

```
 <button onclick="logout()">Logout</button>
    <button onclick="login()">LogIn</button>
    <script>
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        setTimeout(() => {
            window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
                FB.init({
                    appId: 'xxxxxxx', //My app id here
                    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                    // the session
                    xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
                    version: 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
                });
                checkFBLoginStatus();
            }
        })

        function checkFBLoginStatus() {
            FB.getLoginStatus((response) => {
                console.log(response)
            });
        }

        function logout() {
            FB.logout(function(response) {
                console.log(response)
            })
        }

        function login() {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                console.log(response)
                FB.api('/me?fields=id,email,name', function(response) {

                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                });
            }, {
                scope: 'email'
            })
        }


        function onLoginSuccess() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                console.log(response)
            })
        }
    </script>
```

I am getting the response on logout and login

Here are my questions

1. On FB.api call i am getting only ID and Name whereas i need user email to set as an unique user identifier.
2. When is the condition i can achieve not_authorized. I am getting status 'connected' if i login and 'unknown' if i logout. I am not able to reproduce the condition un_authorized, so that i could code for it.

Comment: _"whereas i need user email to set as an unique user identifier"_ - the documentation for the `email` permission already tells you that you won’t be able to get an email from every Facebook user. The app-scoped user id is your unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ID of the user to identify him, not the email. Users do not have to have an email, they can also use their phone number to login. Make sure you get asked for the email permission in the login process/popup. Also, use this form instead:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'id,email,name'}, function(response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```